# MySQL wants a password but it's empty

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, authentication, password

```
mysql -uroot
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

mysql -uroot -p
Enter password:       <-- leave blank, hit enter without entering anything

mysql>                <-- i am logged in
```

NOTE: This is a new mysql instance installation

So if the password is blank, why won't it log me in without a -p flag?

For a little clarification. I am running into this issue when attempting to change the password using a script:

We're using a bash script to do that.

- `mysqladmin -u root password abc` wouldn't work (access denied)
- `mysqladmin -u root -p password abc` cannot be used because it prompts for a password and we need to automate this.
- `mysqladmin -u root -p'' password abc` is not working either

Answer (score 2):

it's a default behavior for blank password.There is nothing wrong with it.

To allow yourself to log in to MySQL without having to type a password at the prompt, add your password to a file called .my.cnf in your home directory.

```
[client]
user=root
password=
```

Now change the permission of .my.cnf file to either 400 or 600.

```
chmod 400 .my.cnf
```

OR

```
chmod 600 .my.cnf
```

Now

```
mysql
```

command will automatically log you in.

Comment: Please beware about security implications for usernames with nonblank password. Nevermind for blank ones ;)

Comment: The issue would show up when changing the password using mysqladmin, we're using a bash script to do that. `mysqladmin -u root password abc` wouldn't work (access denied) and `mysqladmin -u root -p password abc` cannot be used because it prompts for a password and we need to automate this. `mysqladmin -u root -p'' password abc` is not working either.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa myqladmin -u root password "abc" should work for blank password. Try with quotes

Comment: Disregard the comment if you read it: It's not working... I was connected to incorrect server. So it's still not working... even with quotes - it's prompting for a password

Comment: @gAMBOOKa it will only work for the blank password like i already mentioned. For nonblank passwords, try mysqladmin -u root -pyourpassword "newpassword" for your automation bash script

Comment: The password is blank. I can do a `mysql -uroot -p` and simply hit enter when prompted for password, it works.

Comment: well that is strange. I just did all the steps in my laptop and it worked as expected. sorry friend we could not solve your issue

Comment: It works on another server for me as well.

Comment: then something funny is going on with mysql. Are you running multiple instances mysql on same machine ??? When running multiple instances of mysql, client (eg mysql, mysqladmin) program gets confused as to which server the command is expected to execute for !!

Comment: Yes, i am running multiple instances, but I am also adding in the -S flag for selecting the right socket. Any details on this confusion? Related articles? This might be it.

Comment: how about passing socket path to mysqladmin command itself too !!

Comment: I do that, of course

Answer (score 0):

It's sending a password, despite not being given one; it's getting that from somewhere.

Check for a file at `~/.my.cnf`.

But, set a password for your root user ASAP - unless you're perhaps being logged in anonymously (`select current_user();`)?

Answer (score 0):

Because MySQL is set to use password auth, and if you don't provide the password on the command invocation (leaving it at "-p"), it would prompt you to then enter your MySQL password.

It may be easier to think of your password as being a carriage-return rather than being blank